# How to count chars in string but with newline as one character

Tags: python

I try to count characters in result of textarea. It can contains many lines.

```
text = '''1
2
3'''
```

if I use `len(text)` the result is 7, because it counts each newline as two characters (which is quite possible CR+LF are two characters). But I want to count it as one character - is there any method or I have to count newlines and substract it?

Comment: Perhaps replacing the `\r\n` with `\n` might simplify it and make it more cross platform.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is secure to change form input - what if browser requires cr+lf? Or you mean not to change text just analyze its clone with replaced \r\n

Comment: Yeah, I meant only for counting. I think your solution is fine from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 1):

For now I use:

```
number_of_chars = len(text)-text.count('\r')
```